# How do we skip frame, calculate number of frames and get current frame with video reader

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using Opencv for video decoding now. I can play the video with no problem. However, I could not find a way to skip frame, get total number of frames and current frame number. Is there a way to use VideoReader like VideoCapture? I have gone through their api and could not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

***OpenCV*** is Open Source library. If you use ***VideoCapture*** then the object of this class has any methods:

1. To skip a frame you should read 2 times a frame.
2. To get total number of frames as follows:

   ```
   cv::VideoCapture m_capture;
   ....
   int totalFrames = m_capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
   ```
3. To get a current frame number:

   ```
   int currentFrame = m_capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
   ```

For detailed information visit the OpenCV documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html.

Comment: This is not for opencv cuda. The solution i need should specifically for opencv cuda only.

Comment: I guess @Vivian wants similar feature of Video Capture in Video Reader, not Video Capture itself